# Formatting and Filesystem Issues on SD Card - Differences in Boot Sector and Dirty Bit

Tags: formatting, filesystems, sd-card, fat32

I'm experiencing several issues with an SD card, and I'd like to provide more details to help the community understand the problem more comprehensively:

> > > I'm using an SD card with my Android smartphone. The card is primarily used for storing photos, videos, etc.
> > > Recently, when i trying to format the drive i've got a error message like "Error synchronizing after initial wipe: Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark, O)" on my  Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS machine.
> > > The SD card is currently formatted as FAT32.

When I run** fsck.fat** on the SD card, I receive the following message:

```
Differences between boot sector and its backup.
This is mostly harmless. Differences: (offset:original/backup)
  65:01/00
Not automatically fixing this.
Dirty bit is set. Fs was not properly unmounted and some data may be corrupt. Automatically removing dirty bit.
*** Filesystem was changed ***
```

How significant are these differences between the primary and backup boot sectors, particularly the difference at offset 65? What do these differences mean for the integrity of the filesystem?
I can't do any read-write operations on this sd-card.This is totally stuck

Answer (score 0):

It may not be significant at all... That would depend on whether or not you had ***mount***ed SD card before you ran `fsck.fat` on it. You will **always** get an error message if you run `fsck.fat` on it ***while it is mounted***.